# Integral with the branch points

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-cuts, branch-points

At the problem of energy transfer from the two-dimensional crystal molecule to arise such here integrals:
 $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{Q^2+k^2}  (E-\sqrt{Q^2+k^2} ) }
{(k-a)(k+a)}e^{ikg} dk  ,где g,Q \geqslant 0$$

Breaking integral into the sum of two and counting the one in the sense of the principal value of residues
 $$-\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{  ({Q^2+k^2} ) }
{(k-a)(k+a)}e^{ikg} dk=\dfrac{\pi(a^2+Q^2)}{a}\sin(ga)$$ 
 [url]http://prntscr.com/djachg[/url]

But in another integral

$$E\cdot\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{Q^2+k^2}}
{(k-a)(k+a)}e^{ikg} dk$$

There are two branch points k = -iQ and k = iQ (if not mistaken).
If I'll contour here so
 [Contour of integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp5Cj.jpg)

The integral over such a closed circuit is nulyu.I then remains to estimate the integral over Q branch points at $r\to0,$ And the integral of singularities at $r\to0 $ And the integral over the semi-major axis radius R($R\to\infty   $).

Have I chosen bypass circuit. And it seemed to me that some of them are zero (if, in general, equal to) and find the answer?

Comment: somehow i have a deja-vu...

Comment: do you only need an approximation? then negelect the contributions from the brachpoint they are exponentially supressed for reasonable values of $g>0$ compared to the oscillating contribution from the singularities

Comment: btw i would define the bc to be a ray from $iQ$ up to $i \infty$ that should simplify the analysis quiete a bit

Comment: No, I do not need approkimatsiya.
And somebody can describe the calculation of the integral and how to carry out the cut, to evaluate the integral?

Comment: i might be wrong but i doubt that a closed form expression for this integral exists

Comment: have you asked the same question yesterday?